# Ошибка Run-time check failure #2. Number corrupted

Tags: runtime

Ошибка Run-time check failure #2 - stack around variable 'number' was corrupted. Не понимаю, где могла возникнуть ошибка: пишу список на си. В результате в функцию печати указатель возвращает NULL и, соответственно, список не печатается. Заранее спасибо

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>

struct avia
{
    int number;
    float time;
    char destination;
    avia* next;
};
void instructions();
void createlist(avia* pbegin);
void insert(avia** elem, int number, float time, char destination);
int deleteelem(avia** elem, int number);
void printlist(avia* current);
void deletelist(avia* current);
int isempty(avia* elem);
int main()
{
    avia* head=NULL;
    int number;
    int choice;
    float time;
    char destination;
    instructions();
    scanf_s("%d", &choice);
    while (choice != 6)
    {
        switch (choice)
        {
        case 1:
            createlist(head);
            break;
        case 2:
            printf("Enter a number: \n");
            scanf_s("%d", &number);
            printf("Enter time:\n");
            scanf_s("%f", &time);
            printf("Enter destination:\n");
            scanf_s("%s", &destination, 30);
            insert(&head, number, time, destination);
            printlist(head);
            break;
        case 3:
            if (!isempty(head))
            {
                printf("Enter a number you want to delete\n");
                scanf_s("%d", &number);
                if (deleteelem(&head, number))
                {
                    printf("Object deleted");
                    printlist(head);
                }
                else
                {
                    printf("Number not found");
                }
            }
            else
            {
                printf("The list is empty\n");
            }
            break;
        case 4:
            if (!isempty(head))
            {
                deletelist(head);
            }
            else
            {
                printf("The list is empty\n");
            }
            break;
        case 5:
            if (!isempty(head))
            {
                printlist(head);
            }
            else
            {
                printf("The list is empty\n");
            }
            break;
        default:
            printf("Invalid choice\n");
            instructions();
            break;
        }
        printf("?\n");
        scanf_s("%d", &choice);
    }
    printf("End of run\n");
    return 0;
}
void instructions()
{
    printf("Enter choice:\n1 create an empty list\n 2 insert an element into the list.\n3 delete an element from the list. \n 4 delete the whole list\n 5 print the list\n 6 end program. \n");
}
void createlist(avia* elem)
{
    elem = NULL;
}
void insert(avia** elem, int number, float time, char destination)
{
    avia* newelem;
    newelem = (avia*)malloc(sizeof(avia)); 
    if (newelem != NULL)
    {
        newelem->number = number;
        newelem->time = time;
        newelem->destination = destination;
        newelem->next = NULL;
    }
    else printf("List not inserted. No memory available\n");
}
int deleteelem(avia** elem, int number)
{
    avia* previous;
    avia* current;
    avia* temp;
    if (number == (*elem)->number)
    {
        temp = *elem;
        *elem = (*elem)->next;
        free(temp);
        return(number);
    }
    else
    {
        previous = *elem;
        current = (*elem)->next;
        while (current != NULL && current->number != number)
        {
            previous = current;
            current = current->next;
        }
        if (current != NULL)
        {
            temp = current;
            previous = current->next;
            free(temp);
            return(number);
        }
    }
}
void printlist(avia* current)
{
    if (current == NULL)
    {
        printf("The list is empty\n");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("The list is: ");
        while (current != NULL)
        {
            printf("%d, %f, %s ->", current->number, current->time, current->destination);
            current = current->next;
        }
        printf("NULL");
    }
}
void deletelist(avia* current)
{
    avia* temp;
    if (current == NULL)
    {
        printf("The list is empty\n");
    }
    else
    {
        while (current != NULL)
        {
            temp = current;
            current = current->next;
            free(temp);
        }
    }
}
int isempty(avia* elem)
{
    return elem == NULL;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
char destination;
...
scanf_s("%s", &destination, 30); // эти тридцать букв куда читаются?
```

Comment: в функции insert вводятся в элемент списка

Comment: @РостиславЮшкевич Тип `char` - это *одна* буква. А Вы туда сколько вводите? Не говоря уже о терминаторе `\0`.

Comment: понял, спасибо большое. А может у вас есть идеи, по какой причине вместо печати списка всегда выдается сообщение "The list is empty"? насколько я понимаю, проблема в указателе на элемент списка, но не могу понять, где

Comment: @РостиславЮшкевич Идея есть. Вы в функции `insert` не присваиваете значение параметру `elem` - и вообще его не используете.

Comment: мое почтение. Очень мне помогли, спасибо

Comment: @РостиславЮшкевич На здоровье. Успехов!